# Unable to connect to specific network in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am unable to connect to specific network in Ubuntu after upgrading to 18.04. It shows connected but I am unable to access internet. When I try to access with mobile hotspot, it is working fine.

Result of ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 10:bf:48:09:7b:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 369  bytes 34749 (34.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 369  bytes 34749 (34.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
    inet6 fe80::e8e9:1762:a6fb:d77a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100 (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 352  bytes 22027 (22.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
tun1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.8.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.2
    inet6 fe80::6ffb:a140:5d12:5359  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 9  bytes 1040 (1.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10  bytes 1088 (1.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::5e2e:88d6:f08:a049  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:85:de:22:1d:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 97  bytes 18444 (18.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 134  bytes 19607 (19.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Result of route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         srikar-K55VM    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         csp1.zte.com.cn 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
128.0.0.0       srikar-K55VM    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
srikar-k55vm    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlan0
```

When it happened the first time, I have tried

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe -r ssb
```

It worked then. But when I switched to hotspot for a while and came back again to the previous network, it stopped working. After that even the above commands did not help.

Result of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3"

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI
Express Card Reader [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
```

Regards,
Srikar

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6, I have updated the question with the ouput of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3".
Thanks, Srikar.

Comment: So how Broadcom drivers are related? You have an Atheros card. It lloks like you have problems with routing, not the wireless.

Comment: I see. Can you help me resolve the issue? Thanks, Srikar

Comment: It is hard to tell what the tunnels are for.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. How do you recommend I proceed with this?